# Is Appcelerator Titanium and similar cross platforms stable for products development at startup?

Tags: titanium, cross-platform

I have experiences with native Android and iOS development using native SDKs. Now I am looking at some cross platforms solutions. And it seems like Titanimum is the most free popular solution. But I wonder whether it is stable enough for product development? Because I have experienced many freaky bugs from native development before, some bugs even came from inside native SDKs itself.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium is used for many production apps. It has been around for over 5 years and is pretty stable. Of course, sometimes bugs happen, like all software, but besides that, no issues.

Some apps, which are in production, on which I worked, and which are in production to large audiences: `Roamler` and `Peerby`. But there are many many many more production apps out there.

Comment: Oh, those apps looks awesome. Are iOS and Android versions of those apps fully developed with Titanium? And in development, do you often need to switch to native code with Objective C (Swift)  or Java?

Comment: Both apps only use modules provided by either the community or Appcelerator. No native code has been written especially for these apps. Neither on Android nor on iOS

Comment: Oh great, can you introduce me some modules which you used and where can I find other necessary modules? By the way, how do you think about Adobe Air?

Comment: Adobe Air still alive? Anyways, feel free to join the community and ask around. There are hundreds of great modules. Join community: http://tislack.org. Check for modules: http://gitt.io

Comment: Yeah, according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_AIR), it is still developing and has released new versions recently. Why do you think it is stopped developing?

Comment: I can offer you "Fantastic Library". You can see, that you do not feel any differences between Titanium and native app.